# Can't make dll import from to my exe process because of dependencis missing in exe but exist on dll

Tags: visual-c++, c++17

I have 2 project

1. dll that include some other 3rd party dll and use them (don't have the sources - just using it)
2. some testing exe process that I using to check my dll that I developing

Now, I wrote simple class in the dll and I try to use this class instance on my exe tester - and I get an error about that the exe does not find the 3rd party include files that my dll include

How to solve it? How to import all the dependencies missing dll file to my tester exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no automated solution that I know of to retrieve include paths.

If you include an external header inside one of your DLL's headers, then it also becomes a dependency for your users. You need to abstract away that external code and not expose it in your interface in any way if you want to remove the dependency.